# how can i implement pagination with sanity next13

Tags: next.js, pagination, sanity

so i was trying to add pagination to my website using sanity and next13 but i ran into a couple of problems, mainly if i should fetch all my products then slice them according to the page number, which for me looks like a bad approach since it would use too much time and bandwidth.then i thought about fetching only 10 products each time while remembering the last product's id like so:

```
*[_type=="product" && count((categories[]->slug.current)[@ in ["${category}"]]) > 0 && _id > ${lastProductId}] | order(_id) [0...10] {
      name,
      price,
      image,
      slug
    }
```

but what if i jump from page 1 to 3 ? or if i go back to a previous page ? plz help i've been struggling to find the best thing to do.